# Reading CSV column name starting with number (Python)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I had a question about reading in a column name from a CSV file into my python program starting with a number? So my CSV datafile called `Teams.csv` has columns with names or headers such as `R`, `AB`, `H`, `2B`, `3B`, etc. Specifically, the CSV file is the Lahman's Baseball Database's [Teams.csv file](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/).

Now when I read this file in Python, I use this:

```
#imported pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Teams.csv")

#Get stats for offense
R = df.R
AB = df.AB
H = df.H
```

and these work fine, but when I try to import `2B` and `3B` though

```
doubles = df.2B
triples = df.3B
```

these give a syntax error because of Python not having variables start with digits.

Is there a way around this that I can do within Python itself? Or do I have to go into the CSV and rename the headers to lets say `X2B` and `X3B`?

I rather not do the latter, because Lahman's Baseball Database has A LOT of CSV files.

Comment: would it be possible, to change map them into strings and save to variables, like variable = str(2B)?

Comment: I don't know Panda `DataFrame`. But maybe you can do `df["2B"]`.

Comment: unfortunately not -- if I end up doing df.variable, it'll look for variable as the column header

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Aren't `2B` etc. column headers? Don't you want to get columns?

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't use dot notation to access columns as it becomes ambiguous if you're trying to access a column, an attribute or a method on the df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```
doubles = df['2B']
triples = df['3B']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and if you would prefer to access the columns by `dot` notation, to rename the column names conditionally:

```
#Check if a column name is starting with digit and 
#if it is starting rearrange column name to start with a character
df.columns = [ ''.join([x[1],x[0]]) if re.match('^\d',x) else x for x in df.columns]
```

Will produce this result:

[image]